# Allow multiple date formats in symfony2 form builder

Tags: symfony

A client requested this. He wants to allow multiple date formats for a birthday field. The documentation didn't give me any clues how to realize it and neither did google.

Anyone who experienced such a request before and has a lead how to achieve this?

Currently it looks like this:

```
$builder->add('xxx', 'birthday', array('widget' => 'single_text', 'invalid_message' => 'some message (dd-MM-yyyy)', 'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle different date formats in your form, you ought to look at  [DataTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)
It helps you to transform data from one format to another, for example:

```
2013-03-26 ==transform==> 2013/03/26
2013.03.26 ==transform==> 2013/03/26
26.03.2013 ==transform==> 2013/03/26
```

Answer (score 1):

Data transformer should **NOT** be used in this case.

The main point of data transformer is to convert a data **back and forth** between `view <=> norm <=> model`.

It's not your case, you don't want a bidirectional transformation.

What you want is to filter the data, and for that, you can use a **form event**:

```
$builder->add(
    $builder
        ->create('xxx', 'birthday', [...])
        ->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function(FormEvent $event) {
                $value = $event->getData();
                // Do the filtering you want (for example replacement of special chars with a dash)
                // $value = preg_replace('[^\d]', '-', $value)
                $event->setData($value);
            }
        )
);
```

And you are done, the data is filtered on the `PRE_SUBMIT` event, before validation.

I wrote this example from memory and didn't tested it, maybe you'll should adapt it (and add your field option instead of `[...]`.